# How can I access element reference from *ngFor loop element?

Tags: angular, ngfor

How can I access element reference from ngFor loop?
I made some sample here.

In TypeScript

```
public onUpload(itemId: number):void {
   // how can I access element?
   this.listContainer.nativeElement.scrollTo(    ???     );
}
```

Markup

```
<ul #list_container style="overflow-y:scroll;">
  <li *ngFor="var item of items">
    {{item.id}} - {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what you trying to achieve ? please bit more explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use them either by using

```
@ViewChild('list_container') list_container :ElementRef;
```

then you can use it as

```
 this.listContainer.nativeElement.scrollTo(..)
```

If you want tp access nth child, you can use

```
@ViewChildren(ListItemDirective) list_container: QueryList<ListItemDirective>;
```

In this case you need to have a directive for the iterated children

```
@Directive({selector: 'list-item-directive'})
class ListItemDirective {
}
```

You need to modify your markup as

```
<li *ngFor="var item of items" list_container>
```

You can access the last child by using `this.list_container.last`

Comment: I need access to n-th child.
this way is just access to list container though. :(

Answer (score 1):

Use queryselector.

```
this.elementref.nativeElement.queryselector('ul li:nth-child(2)') 
{
    // do ur stuff here
}
```